# Find Element By Class with Spaces Not Working

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to locate the following WebElement by class name:

```
<div class="aui-column-content aui-column-content-last lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-actions-content">
```

And since it has a space, I've attempted to use both css and xpath to find it like so ...

```
WebElement folderActions = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='aui-column-content aui-column-content-last lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-actions-content ']"));


WebElement folderActions = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='aui-column-content aui-column-content-last lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-actions-content ']"));
```

But both solutions are returning a NoSuchElementException.  Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** Here is some adjacent html ...

```
<div id="aui_3_2_0_11858" class="portlet-body">
    <div class="top-links-container">
    <div id="aui_3_2_0_11857" class="aui-layout ">
        <div id="aui_3_2_0_11856" class="aui-layout-content ">
            <div class="taglib-header ">
                <span class="header-back-to">
                <h1 class="header-title">
            </div>
            <div class="aui-column aui-w75 lfr-asset-column lfr-asset-column-details aui-column-first ">
                <div class="aui-column-content aui-column-content-first lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-details-content ">
            </div>
        <div id="aui_3_2_0_11855" class="aui-column aui-w25 lfr-asset-column lfr-asset-column-actions aui-column-last">
            <div class="aui-column-content aui-column-content-last lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-actions-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that indicates multiple classes, not one class-name with spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `contains()` function with `xpath`. And, as @Shoham A mentioned it does look like as multiple classes. Provide more `html` so we can help you with writing more perfect selector.

`//div[contains(@class,'aui-column-content aui-column-content-last lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-actions-content')]`

And, use [explicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) wait to make sure the element is present before started using that.

```
By byXpath = By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'aui-column-content aui-column-content-last lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-actions-content')]");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byXpath ));
```

**Edit**
`//div[contains(@class,'aui-column-content-last')]` should be enough to search for the target `div`. At least for the `html` provided by OP.

**NOTE:** Thinking the `aui-column-content-last` is unique on the page

Comment: No cigar. Are we certain this "contain" method accounts for the multi-class problem I'm having here?  I'll post more adjacent html.

Comment: @user2150250 `contains()` does work pretty well. But, the class name is pretty long. Which may not a good idea to use anyway. More `html` will help

Comment: @user2150250  `//div[contains(@class,'aui-column-content-last')]` this is enough. `Contains()` gives you the ability to search wit partial match

Comment: I am still curious as to why the `contains` with multiple class names never worked to find the element though. I tried it every which way that was suggested here in the answers.

Comment: @user2150250 It absolutely does work - if you pay close attention to the _whitespace_ in the attribute value and reproduce it in the XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

The Xpath expression in your question **would work** if there was no whitespace character at the end of it:

```
//div[@class='aui-column-content aui-column-content-last lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-actions-content']
```

this will definitely find this `div` element. I'm not saying that this is the best method to locate it, but everybody seems to think path expressions somehow do not work with multiple classes.

**EDIT**

You have updated the question. Now, the `div` again looks slightly different and only

```
//div[contains(@class,'aui-column-content aui-column-content-last   lfr-asset-column-content lfr-asset-column-actions-content')]
```

will find it. Any reason you cannot use the @id attribute of that `div`?

Comment: @user2150250 Then you either incorrectly apply this XPath expression or did _not_ faithfully reproduce the HTML that serves as your input. But to be sure you'd need to show a _complete_ HTML document.

Comment: My apologies. I don't know how the extra spaces got in there when I was copying over the html.  The original in my question is correct.

Comment: The id attribute cannot be used because it is different for every page that this particular element is used in.  The only constant is the classes.

Answer (score -1):

Have you met jQuery ? I do not have much experience with XPath, but it makes selecting elements easier, as:

```
$(".classname")
```

for CSS,

```
.aui-column-content.aui-column-content-last...
{
color: black;
}
```

should do it. Hope I helped!